# Is there a command/program/Cmdlet that writes to the prompt buffer?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to see if I can write the output of a command to the prompt buffer to allow for further editing? Something like this, where `Write-PromptBuffer` is the command desired:

```
PS C:\> echo "foo bar" | Write-PromptBuffer
PS C:\> foo bar
```

Something equivalent to what zsh does with `print -z` (see http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide03.html)

My main motivation for this is something along the lines of:

```
PS C:\> Get-Content (Get-PSReadLineOption).HistorySavePath | fzf
```

Which would "dump" the selected (accepted in `fzf` lingo) entry as an editable command in the prompt.

(Note: I'm familiar with `PSFzf`, but I'm trying to find a general purpose command to do this as I have other use cases that would benefit from this)

Comment: How about control r to search for a previous command?

Comment: That "works" for the specified use-case... even if ctrl-r doesn't do fuzzy match, or show you a list of "currently matching".  It does, however, allow you to ctrl-e on the match to be dropped into the prompt with the matched string. I'm looking for something more generic to allow me to do this for not just history look-ups.

Comment: There's a lot you can do with psreadline key bindings:  `PSReadlineKeyHandler -bound`  Plus there's windows, emacs, and vi mode.

Comment: There is an `add-history` command...

Answer (score 1):

The PSReadLine module can insert into the buffer, for example

```
[Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::Insert("foo bar")
```

However, as this is intended to edit the current line buffer and not the following line you will need so do something like this

```
#pipeline to variable $myBuffer function
function Write-PromptBuffer {
    param (  
        [parameter(ValueFromPipeline, ValueFromRemainingArguments = $true)]
        $global:myBuffer
        )
}
#Add a PSReadLineKeyHandler to insert $myBuffer
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Key Alt+x `
    -ScriptBlock {
    param($key, $arg)   # The arguments are ignored in this example
    #write to buffer
    [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::Insert($myBuffer)
}
```

Now populate $myBuffer with a string and call it with Alt+w

```
PS C:\> echo "foo bar" | Write-PromptBuffer
PS C:\> foo bar
```

Alternatively and not pretty, you could use SendKeys

```
function Write-PromptBuffer {
    param (  
        [parameter(ValueFromPipeline, ValueFromRemainingArguments = $true)]
        $myBuffer
        )
    (new-object -com wscript.shell).SendKeys($myBuffer)
}
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Curious why you say that the `SendKeys` method is "not pretty". Is there something "morally" wrong about it?

Comment: Its difficult to implement safely and often problematic. Keypresses are global so a few Alt+F4's and you'll be shutting down Windows or forget its running a long SendKeys and flip to another application and it'll continue sending. However, for short controlled bursts it might just do what you need.